# Minimum of Multivariate Pareto

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, pareto-distribution

Suppose I have a multivariate Pareto distribution with cdf,

$$  Prob(Z_{1}<z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}<z_{n}) = H(\textbf{z}) = 1 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (T_{i}z_{i}^{-\theta})^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}} \right)^{1-\rho} $$

This is the Pareto distribution derived in this [paper](https://arkolakis.com/wp-content/uploads/research/MVPareto/multivariate-distribution-pareto.pdf). I compute the distribution of the minimum and I get that

\begin{align*}
Prob(min(z_{1},\dots,z_{n})\leq c )&=1-Prob(min(z_{1},\dots,z_{n})> c ) \\
&= 1- Prob\left( \cap_{i=1}^{N} (Z_{i}>c) \right)  \\
&=1 - \bar{H}(\textbf{c}) \\
&=1-[1-H(\textbf{c})] \\
&=1-c^{-\theta} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}T_{i}^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}} \right)^{1-\rho} 
\end{align*}

where $\bar{H}(\textbf{c})=1-H(\textbf{c})$ and $\textbf{c}=\left\{c,\dots,c \right\}$.

Is this okay?

Now what confuses me is that this seems to be the same distribution of the maximum. Is this weird?

Comment: You forgot to raise a probability to the $n^\text{th}$ power in the second line of your derivation.

Comment: I do not think so. The cdf above is Multivariate, z is a vector of $z_{i}$. I changed it to bold to clarify the notation.

Comment: Where, then do you obtain that $1-H$ is the survival function of the minimum?

Comment: Maybe that is where I am wrong. I made some edits to clarify my steps.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, because it suddenly changes meaning: initially $H$ is a function of an $n$-vector $\mathbf{z},$ then it becomes a function of a number $c.$

Comment: I see your confusion, define $\textbf{c}$ as an $N \times 1$ vector with a constant equal to c in each entry.

Comment: I'm not confused: I'm giving you a strong hint...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124197/discussion-between-maney-and-whuber).

Comment: @whuber thanks so much for the reply. However, I really do not see the mistake.

Comment: @whuber Isn't the joint survivor function in this case just $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (T_{i}z_{i}^{-\theta})^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}} \right)^{1-\rho}$, if all $z_{i}=c$, then the result follows.

Comment: @whuber Now, I see my mistake. Thanks so much. The complement of all the $Z_{i}$s being larger than c is not that all of them are smaller than c. Still not sure on how to proceed.